# Properties of morphisms induced by divisors on curves

Tags: tag-removed, ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, algebraic-curves

There are a few properties from Hartshorne IV on curves that I am trying to verify.  Let $D$ be an effective divisor on a curve (integral scheme of dimension 1, proper over $k$, regular) $X$, $\dim |D| = 1$, and $f$ the induced morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

1. The degree of $D$ is the degree of $f$, where $\deg(f) = [K(X) : K(\mathbb{P}^1)]$.
2. In lemma IV.4.2, Hartshorne seems to claim that all points in the support of $D$ are in the same fiber.
3. Again in lemma IV.4.2, Hartshorne seems to claim that if $[K(X) : K(\mathbb{P}^1)]$ is Galois, then an automorphism of the Galois group permutes elements of the fiber.

Comment: By Hartshorne II.6.9 we have more generally $\deg f^∗E=\deg f\cdot \deg E$ for any $E$ on $P^1$.

Comment: Your first question is already answered. For the second, by definition, $f(P)=D'$ where $D'$ is the unique effective divisor linearly equivalent to $D$ with $D' \ge P$. So it is clear that $f(P)=D$ if $P$ is in the support of $D$. The third question is similarly straightforward.

Comment: Ah this makes so much more sense!  I was not aware of the "definition" you mentioned; if it's in Hartshorne then I missed it.  So for the third, the action of a Galois element fixes the elements of $\mathbb{P}^1$, which I'm identifying with effective divisors linearly equivalent to $D$.  Since these divisors also define the fibers of my map, it must be that the fibers are permuted.